# unison force option not recognized

Tags: unison

I'm trying to do a one way synchronize (ie mirroring) of a local directory with a remote one on an accessible ssh server using unison and the option "-force" however the command is not recognized:

```
$ unison -force /home/localuser/test_sync ssh://anuser@192.168.1.111//home/anuser/test_sync

Usage: unison [options]
    or unison root1 root2 [options]
    or unison profilename [options]

For a list of options, type "unison -help". For a tutorial on basic usage, type "unison -doc tutorial". For other documentation, type "unison -doc topics".
```

tried multiple variations but seems -force option is not recognized.
Notice I want to use command line without creating profiles for each directory.

Answer (score 3):

ok found that -force must be inserted at the end repeating the path that must be mirrored:

```
unison /home/localuser/test_sync ssh://anuser@192.168.1.111//home/anuser/test_sync -force /home/localuser/test_sync
```